# Changing default app to open a certain extension, but keeping the previous icon?

Tags: icon, text-editor, uti, bbedit

I use TextWrangler to open code files, such as `.php, .ccs, .js`, etc.

But it assigns the same icon to every file. How can I get the original icons back to each extension while TextWrangler is still the default app to open them?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you want is what happens when **using Xcode as the default application**.

The behavior you want is not possible with TextWrangler for the following reason: 
Textwrangler does not distinguish the icons for `*.php *.ccs...` like Xcode. Therefore it does not store different icons for different filetypes (`PHP.icns, CCS.icns...`).

Instead **TextWrangler only stores one icon for all filetypes**: `TextWranglerTextDoc.icns`

This icon is located at:

1. right-click on TextWrangler -> show package contents
2. navigate to `.../Contents/Resources/TextWranglerTextDoc.icns`

Comment: thanks. So could I manipulate TextWrangler's Info.Plist to accomplish this or is that too far fetched?

Comment: Yes, I've done it and it works so far: I merged the ``Resources`` folder from ``Xcode.app`` with the one from ``Textwrangler.app``. Then I replaced the entry ``Document Types`` in the ``Info.plist`` for TextWrangler with the ones in Xcode. I hope that's all and safe...

Comment: This doesn't work for me, sadly.